# I've followed the corda bootcamp but I'm still facing a problem with TokenIssueFlowInitiator with PartyA

Tags: corda

Could someone please point out if I've made mistakes in the code of TokenState, TokenContract, and TokenIssueFlowInitiator from the following link:

https://github.com/shanmukhipriya99/cordapp_bootcamp/tree/v4/src/main/java/bootcamp

[This is what happens in the node of PartyA]

[image]

Please help me out!

Comment: Please check the log file of your node for any errors; you can find it under `/cordapp_bootcamp/build/nodes/PartyA/logs` (or PartyB / PartyC). If you find any errors, update your question with the log output.

Comment: I've checked the log file for PartyA, it's empty.

Answer (score 0):

In the typical corda Bootcamp, you want to make sure to take a look at the solutions.md file here: https://github.com/corda/bootcamp-cordapp/blob/v4/Solutions.md

It has the exact answers for what should be in the different files that are written during the sample project.

good luck!

Comment: I tried that already and it works absolutely fine, but I wanted to know where I went wrong. I also tried to compare both the codes and made some changes. Now the flow is getting issued on PartyA and the command "run vaultQuery contractStateType: bootcamp.TokenState" works fine with PartyA but doesn't work with PartyB.